# Not to show the command line of the hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am using free distribution of hadoop downloaded from the apache foundation website under windows, what I start the hadoop cluster through start-dfs.cmd command, and then there will be two black command line that will be prompted, what should I do so that these two windows runs in background?

Comment: are you downloaded you hadoop binary distribution ? Make sure that JAVA_HOME are properly configure with sufficient .NET frame work.

Comment: Hi , yes i donwloaded the binary distribution and java_home is correctly set , the problem i would like when i launch the start-dfs.cùd command to launch the hadoop cluster i would like to hide the datanode and the namenode and to make them run in background ?what can i do that THanks

Comment: Did you try `start /B start-dfs.cmd`?

Comment: actually am running the command from a java source code as here     def startHDFS() {
    try {
   
   val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe Start-Process C:\\Hadoop\\Hadoop-2.3\\sbin\\start-dfs.cmd -verb RunAs")
Thread.sleep(5000);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hadoop has been successfully launched",
       "Hadoop Distributed File System", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      logger.info("HDFS Started")
      
      

    }

Comment: hi i just tried it the same problem

Comment: Rather using powershell , Please use Process to handle these scenario..